# Как правильно сделать get запрос для instagram?

Tags: php, yii2

Когда авторизировался в веб версии **Instagram** и нажал на кнопку количества друзей, то отправился *get*-запрос:

```
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=1215Z2b820144728dde7fzab0d904896a&variables={"id":"1234567890","first":24}
```

Когда я открываю эту ссылку в браузере, то все хорошо, получаю *json* данные.

Теперь пытаюсь сделать это через `Yii2 httpclient`:

```
$client = new Client();
        $response = $client->createRequest()
            ->setMethod('get')
            ->setUrl('https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/')
            ->setData([
                'query_hash' => '1215Z2b820144728dde7facb0d904896a',
                'variables' => '{"id":"123456789","first":24}'
            ])
            ->send();
```

В ответ получаю 403 ошибку.
Как я понял, то в запрос еще нужно отправить нужные заголовки и куки.
Но вопрос - где их взять?

Открыв браузер *networks*, при переходе по ссылке, вижу разный список *cookies*, *headers* в *request* и *response*.

Потом я попробовал сделать так:

```
$client = new Client();
        $firstResponse = $client->createRequest()
            ->setMethod('get')
            ->setUrl('https://www.instagram.com/myPage')
            ->send();

        $secondResponse = $client->createRequest()
            ->setMethod('get')
            ->setUrl('https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/')
            ->setData([
                'query_hash' => '23g53g43g34fDdfsfwe23f23f23f23',
                'variables' => '{"id":"1254563214","first":24}'
            ])
            ->setHeaders($firstResponse->getHeaders())
            ->setCookies($firstResponse->getCookies())
            ->send();
```

`FirstRespons` для того, чтобы получить `cookies`, `headers`, но толку мало, приходят не все данные.

Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: в браузере открывается, потому что вы залогинены, когда же вы посылаете запрос через HttpClient (curl) вам так же необходимо авторизироватся, как это сделать читайте в офф документации

Comment: @madfan41k , я авторизировался через oauth2 instagram

Comment: покажите полный текст ошибки

Comment: @madfan41k
 HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
data пустая